# How do I fill out a textbox generated by the chrome browser itself?

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, browser, automation

I cannot figured out how to fill out a form that is generated by the chrome browser itself, since I cannot inspect any elements of the form I do not know what value to pass into "find_element_by_name".

Here's the browser generated textbox:
[image]

I've tried already using something like driver.send_keys('myusername') but that did not work.

Here's the code snippet that I use to start the browser:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()  
driver.get('mycompanyurl.jsp');
driver.send_keys('myusername')
```

Comment: You can embed the username and password as part of url like this `https://username:password@mycompanyurl.jsp`

Comment: I thought that sub resources were blocked with embedded credentials in chrome URLs.

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work, I'm not sure if it matters but our company URL starts with http and not https.